# How to rewrite Apache directives for Ngnix

Tags: apache, configuration, nginx

Is it possible to rewrite next Apache directives for Ngnix?

#### 1 .Set default charset encoding

Apache:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

#### 2. Redirect to one domain for SEO

Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c\>
    Options +Followsymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com  [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]    
</IfModule>
```

#### 3. Caching files on client side without expiration

```
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
    Header set Expires "Fri, 4 Jan 2022 20:00:00 GMT" 
    FileETag None
```

#### 4.  Text compression

Apache:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
charset utf8;
```

2.

```
server {
    server_name domain.com; 
    server_name domain2.com; 
    server_name www.domain.com; # www.domain2.com in RewriteCond, you mean www.domain.com?

    return 301 $scheme://www.domain2.com/$request_uri;   
}
```

3.

```
expires max;
```

4.

```
gzip on
```